# Excluding invisible form elements from FormData object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a combination of Javascript and jQuery to create a `FormData` object to send form data via AJAX request. This was my original code:

```
// $form is a jQuery object of the form in question
var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
```

My problem is finding a concise way to exclude invisible (i.e. `.not(':visible')`) elements from the data collected by the `FormData` object. I know that I could easily do this using jQuery's `serialize()` method, but I need to use `FormData` in this particular instance due to the upload of image files.

The only way I have managed to make this work is with the following code:

```
// $form is a jQuery object of the form in question
// Clone the original form
var $formClone = $form.clone();

// Remove invisible items from form
$form.find('input, textarea').not(':visible').remove();

// Collect form data with invisible items removed
var formData = new FormData($form[0]);

// Replace form with cloned form which retains invisible elements
$form.replaceWith($formClone);
```

I can't simply remove invisible elements from the clone and pass that to FormData, as none of the clone is visible unless I attach it to the DOM so all data elements are removed. So, my only solution was to clone the original form, and reserve the clone to re-attach to the DOM after removal of invisible elements from the original form.

I worry that using this method isn't very efficient. Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Comment: You could probably just set the elements that aren't visible to be disabled (`$form.find('input, textarea').not(':visible').prop('disabled', true);`), which would save having to clone the form, remove elements, then replace it again. I'd be surprised if `FormData` included disabled input elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @anthonyGist has pointed out in the comments, set invisible elements to disabled:

```
$(':hidden').prop('disabled', true);
```

Comment: This is a very good and useful, but it disabled the css, js links on my page. any idea how to prevent this to happen.

Comment: @YousefAltaf : You need to disable only the elements under your `form`: `$form.find(':hidden').prop('disabled', true);` Also, keep in mind that it will also disable `<input type=hidden>`.

Answer (score 3):

The FormData has a [delete method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete). So, you can just iterate through the hidden/disabled fields from the form you used to create the FormData and delete the ones you don't want in the object:

```
// $form is a jQuery object of the form in question
var formData = new FormData($form[0]);
form.find(':hidden').each(function(i, field) {
    var fname = $(field).attr('name');
    if(fname) {
        formData.delete(fname);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is useful if you don't want to modify the original form (HTML). There are cases in which after submitting the form you need to show other hidden part of it (but if we use the accepted answer, you will need to enable again some fields). Otherwise, disabling the fields before getting the `FormData` is more elegant.